# Dynamic Colorbox loading position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

This is quick link to color box example.

i need to change and customize place of color box loading

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to control the position

```
$("#colorbox").css("left","200px");
```

You can use the similar to control left, right, top, down. But the the element must be position absolutely.

Comment: inside the jquery lib of colorbox, it is positioned it in center

Answer (score 0):

I have make bold the imported code that need to add
I don't know whether

> $("#colorbox").css("left","200px") <   is the answer. it didn't work for me. SORRY!!!

However I got the solution.

you need to do small changes in side the  jquery.colorbox.js

var
    // ColorBox Default Settings.
    // See http://colorpowered.com/colorbox for details.
    defaults = {
         ***positionTop  : 100,*  <----add this
         *positionLeft : 200,***  <----add this too

change this code looks like below(this code inside the publicMethod.position = function (speed, loadedCallback) {  )

```
    posTop = Math.max($window.height() - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight, 0) / 2 + $window.scrollTop() **+ settings.positionTop**,
    posLeft = Math.max($window.width() - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth, 0) / 2 + $window.scrollLeft() **+ settings.positionLeft**;
```

Then you can simply call colorbox by giving position

$.colorbox({html:data.content,**positionTop: 100** ,**positionLeft : 200**